# Common in scala's Array and List

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala(just start learning it), but have figured out smth strange for me: there are classes Array and List, they both have such methods/functions as `foreach`, `forall`, `map` etc. But any of these methods aren't inherited from some special class(trait). From java perspective if `Array` and `List` provide some contract, that contract have to be declared in interface and partially implemented in abstract classes. Why do in scala each type(Array and List) declares own set of methods? Why do not they have some common type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*But any of these methods aren't inherited from some special class(trait)*

That simply not true.

If you open scaladoc and lookup say `.map` method of Array and List and then click on it you'll see where it is defined:

For list:

[image]

For array:

[image]

See also info about [Traversable](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/trait-traversable.html) and [Iterable](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/trait-iterable.html) both of which define most of the contracts in scala collections (but some collections may re-implement methods defined in Traversable/Iterable, e.g. for efficiency).

You may also want to look at [relations between collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html) (scroll to the two diagrams) in general.

Comment: thanks for comprehensive answer. From my java experience I thought that informatopn about type's parent have to be in declaration of that type, but in case of scala array it says: `extends java.io.Serializable with java.lang.Cloneable`, so it confused me a bit. But now I understand that it is not the whole picture

Comment: @maks then it might be interesting for you to look [at this short article](http://codemonkeyism.com/scala-goodness-richstring/) and Enrich-My-Library pattern (formerly known as Pimp-My-Library pattern).

Comment: Feel free to poach my answer to complement yours.

Answer (score 3):

I'll extend om-nom-nom answer here.

Scala doesn't have an `Array` -- that's *Java* `Array`, and Java `Array` doesn't implement any interface. In fact, it isn't even a proper class, if I'm not mistaken, and it certainly is implemented through special mechanisms at the bytecode level.

On Scala, however, everything is a class -- an `Int` (Java's `int`) is a class, and so is `Array`. But in these cases, where the actual class comes from Java, Scala is limited by the type hierarchy provided by Java.

Now, going back to `foreach`, `map`, etc, they are not methods present in *Java*. However, Scala allows one to add *implicit conversions* from one class to another, and, through that mechanism, add methods. When you call `arr.foreach(println)`, what is really done is `Predef.refArrayOps(arr).foreach(println)`, which means `foreach` belongs to the `ArrayOps` class -- as you can see in the scaladoc documentation.

Comment: I'm still opposed to saying that "`Int` is a class"... That's a fiction, at least insofar as the actual execution of Scala programs goes. But I wanted to point out that there are yet more kinds of (non-subtype) polymorphism in Scala. E.g. Typeclasses and "structural typing."

Comment: @RandallSchulz if we put Int into the collection this won't be a fiction ;-)

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Yes it will. It will be java.lang.Integer.

Comment: @RandallSchulz You consider it a fiction because you take "class" to mean the underlying implementation as a JVM class. I consider the underlying implementation to be irrelevant to the language semantics. That is: "class" has only meaning at compile time -- at run time, it's all bits.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: If we're going with that, then it's _types_ that exist only at compile time with _classes_ being their residue at run-time.

Comment: @RandallSchulz See the Scala specification, chapter 5.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: Could you narrow that down? None of the sections in that chapter seem to speak to the question of whether the `AnyVal` types are classes, per se. However, I read section 12.2 as supporting my assertion: "Value classes are classes whose instances are not represented as objects by the underlying
host system."

Comment: @RandallSchulz Ah, I see your point. Chapter 3, then: "_Every concrete value type_ can be represented as a class type, i.e. a type designator (§3.2.3) that refers to a a class or a trait1 (§5.3), or as a compound type (§3.2.7) representing an intersection of types, possibly with a refinement (§3.2.7) that further constrains the types of its members." Emphasis mine.